# How to display difference between past date and today's date and display them as months and days using jquery

Tags: jquery, date

I am beginner with jquery at a level of 1 i think.

I need your help to implement the following:

I have a textbox in one of form in a medical website that I am working on.

That textbox is used to enter a date in format `YYYY-MM-DD`, What i want is that I want to calculate the difference between the date entered and today's date and display it as months and days such as 2 months and 6 days.

I have no idea from where to start. So any little help will make lot of difference for me.

Answer (score 0):

lyour problem seems more of Javascript nature than JS, simply parse the input date, substract the getTime() of that and current time and divide to get months and days

```
var date = new Date(text.value);
var now = new Date();
var difference = now.getTime() - then.getTime(); /*milliseconds*/
var DayMilliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var MonthMilliseconds = 30 * DayMilliseconds ;    
var months = Math.floor( difference / MonthMilliseconds );
var remaining = difference % MonthMilliseconds ;
var days = Math.floor( remaining / DayMilliseconds );
```